# Contact form 7 | textarea and text field submitting without space in between words

Tags: wordpress, get, contact-form, contact-form-7

contact form 7 | textarea and text field submitting without space in between words. when I added an external URL to submit the form, it is removing all the space from the field on time of submission.
example : 
I have a added a line in textarea: 
    `<pre>Hello this is a test submit</pre>`.

then it is passing to the URL like :

```
<pre>
 www. example.com/ submit.php?your-message=Hellothisisatestsubmit.
</pre>
```

It is not even adding %20 in between words.